# why the following error occurs when I am trying to export the data to pdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

> error: Could not include font metric file

Comment: you should post your code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is missing the `fonts` folder from fpdf, or it can not find the font file.

Answer (score 1):

First [Google result](http://www.google.com/search?q=error:+Could+not+include+font+metric+file) (of thousands): [FPDF error: Could not include font metric file](http://collabtive.o-dyn.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=291)

Answer (score 0):

Post your code and we can take a look, were not Physic :).

- What your PDF Version
- Do you have a fonts directory
- what font file is missing exactly
- Try Search the error codes first